# What does exclusive timing mean and even in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

What does exclusive timing mean and even in postgres?
I looked for the documentation, but I couldn't find it, the difference between the exclusive and inclusive time and why each one has a different time.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fns5J.png)

Comment: Time of the individual node.  Inclusive is a running total.

Comment: thanks for the answer, so the inclusive time would be the total consultation cost?

Comment: https://explain.depesz.com/help

Comment: thank you very much, this documentation is explaining my question.